# Zip Codes & Retrieving them

Tags: php, mysql

In this code I want to query a table called "zipcodes". I want to first check to see if the zip code entered is a valid zip code. Then if it is a valid zip code I want to retrieve that zip code with the matching longitude, latitude, city, & state.

Then after retrieving them I want to place them into another table called "Users". Once in Users table I want to be able to pull the values that are assigned to them to echo in various places on my website.

```
 <?php

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM zipcodes WHERE ZIP='".$user_zip."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

        echo "Please Reenter A Valid Zip Code";
        {

        }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1){
       mysqli
        // Need to put next line of code in users db
          }elseif (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1($con, "INSERT INTO ")){





        // retrieve from the database the city and state
    }elseif ($user_zip == true( $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM zipcodes ZIP,Latitude,Longitude,City,State WHERE  ZIP='".$zip.", Latitude='".$latitude"', Longitude='".$longitude"', City='".$local"', State='".$country"', "'")) {


    {


    }   


    ?>
```

Comment: Just store the `id` of the zip record in the user table. Then do a `join` when you need the location information. Also use parameterized queries. This is going to be open to SQL injections (probably)

Comment: Fix the nonsense code first. This code MUST be generating errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean "nonsense", though +1

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, or is it just me?

Comment: @JBES Thats why I code. Compilers where the first spell checkers :)

Comment: No @Fred-ii- You me and the OP have no idea what they are trying to do

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one rowing @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe us galley slaves should revolt

Comment: @RiggsFolly [You mean this?](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=322)

Comment: Starz, can you be more clear about what problem you are experiencing? "Please help me" is not a problem statement.

Comment: No [more like this](http://imgur.com/a/cxMfV) @Fred-ii-

Comment: Sorry about the code I am new at PHP and I am trying to learn. Thanks  Chris85. That helps.

Comment: I know some of my syntax is off with the curly braces I was going to write more code right there.

Comment: @StarzRisen you should probably finish writing your code and then run it, and fix the errors you get, and see what happens. Also helpful if you think through the logic of what you're trying to do, and then try to express that in PHP, rather than writing up stuff and hoping that magic makes it work.

Comment: So I wrote a review of your code (answer below). I remember when I was a kid (8yo) and got my first 'puter, MSX SVI-728, and skimmed through a couple of BASIC programming books with game code examples. Then I wrote my own game. All sorts of funky lines that had a similar feel to what I saw in the book. But alas all I got was `Syntax Error, Ready OK`. Even my `REM Here the car start driving` directives didn't make it work. I was sure it would work, with some manner of magic, just like the real games. It's been a long journey since. `10 PRINT "RTFM" 20 GOTO 10, READY, OK, RUN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick review of your code. There is no other answer to be made here. My comments begin with `// :`. I've fixed up the basic syntax and indented the code to make it readable.

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM zipcodes WHERE ZIP='".$user_zip."'");

// : Checking if there are 0 or more rows returned.
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "Please Reenter A Valid Zip Code";
// } << : Need a closing bracket here.

{ // : These curlies must be for decorative purposes?
}

// : "If 0 or more rows; else if 1 or more rows". 
// : This'd never run because a previous condition matches; 1 > 0!
elseif(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1) {
    mysqli
    // Need to put next line of code in users db
}

// : You already matched the > 1 condition above. + syntax error!
elseif (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1($con, "INSERT INTO ")) {

// : Fixing that syntax. You probably meant something like:

elseif (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1) {
    mysqli($con, "INSERT INTO [...] ");
}

// : This is totally garbled up, both the PHP and the SQL query:

// retrieve from the database the city and state
/* 
elseif ($user_zip == true( $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM zipcodes ZIP,Latitude,Longitude,City,State WHERE  ZIP='".$zip.", Latitude='".$latitude"', Longitude='".$longitude"', City='".$local"', State='".$country"', "'")) { 
*/

// : You probably meant something like:

elseif ($user_zip == true) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, 
        "SELECT * FROM zipcodes 
            WHERE ZIP='{$zip}' 
                AND Latitude='{$latitude}' 
                AND Longitude='{$longitude}' 
                AND City='{$local}' 
                AND State='{$country}'");
}
```

No magic in the world would make this work -- even with all the syntax corrected. I'd recommend you first spend a bit of time learning PHP (and MySQL) syntax. Then think through the logic of what you want to do. Then try to express that in your code. Start with writing test code for the most simple things. Then work your way up to more complicated stuff. Good luck and happy learning.

Comment: Thank you @Markus AO I will be going to school in the next month or so, so that I maybe able to write code off the top of my head. Right now i am learning through tutorials where I find it easier. But thank you for your help. This made me better understand PHP

Comment: Wish you all success. Do try and find quality tutorials. Don't bother too much with 5+ year-old stuff, anything older than PHP 5.4 and you're missing out on a lot of good stuff that's happened since. Do a search here on SO and see what sources users with more rep and experience link to. Some of the tutorials out there are a bit hopeless, will teach you hacky and/or coarse approaches you'll have to unlearn later on. Glad the review above helped you some. I would've revised the code into a proper form, but alas I'm still not clear on what exactly you're hoping to do in your code.

Comment: Also this big little book here, it will be your best friend for many needs: http://php.net/download-docs.php ... I'm a big fan of the CHM version (do grab the one with user notes), very convenient with the built-in search and index features, seems to be open most of the time when my 'puter is on.